# Equally spacing elements that are a percentage, with padding/margin

Tags: css, flexbox

Been googling around for awhile and found some solutions, but none that work for what I've trying to do. Basically I need to space 4 div equally that are 25% - the margin wide. The tricky part is getting the last to not have a space at the end. Tried:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.child {
  width: 22%;
}
```

But it leaves a space at the end. Seems simple, but I've tried multiple different ways, none work correctly. The tricky part seems to be the percentage width and getting the last element not to have a space on the right.

[image]

Comment: Any demo? With the current code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v2d9raak/) it doesn't leave any space on the sides apart from the default body margin.

Comment: You can use https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/ for building grid system

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for, since what you tried matches the image and is what I think you want. [https://jsfiddle.net/r5zLyzds/](https://jsfiddle.net/r5zLyzds/)

Comment: @Jarc The whole point of using flexbox to avoid archaic grid systems such as Bootstrap.

Comment: You guys we're right, working with Drupal and found it was adding a clearfix class that added blank content at the end of the container. Good 'ole Drupal output... drives you crazy sometimes.

Comment: Yep, I've seen similar problem multiple times, even a pseudo element counted as a flex item, maybe you can set it to display none if you can't remove that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@marc-j was right, Drupal was adding a clearfix which was causing the extra space at the end. This works:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.child {
  width: 22%;
}
```